SharePoint Copilot Search/Azure AI Search Integration
I want to upgrade the existing SharePoint's Out of box search with Microsoft Copilot Search or Azure AI Search to enhance the user experience using SPFx. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Do you have the required licensing? What do you exactly want to achieve with this? Do you want to expand the search scope?

To better help you solve your problem, you can describe your needs in more detail.
